# Optimizing Mode_Rewrite lines

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mode

Could I  Optimize those lines?

```
RewriteRule ^contact/$   index.php?page=contact [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^service/$   index.php?page=service [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ads/$       ads.php$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^posts/$     posts.php$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generalize the "page" thing. Keep in mind though that maintainability is more important than fewer lines in most cases. You should not over-do it.

```
RewriteRule ^ads/$       ads.php$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^posts/$     posts.php$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$   index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My modification works like this: It looks for any specific route. If there is no match, the last rule acts as a fallback and appends the name of the page to `index.php?page=`.